# How can i detect from which device my application is registered?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am working with an application in which when the application is registered with the device,i want to get the information in database that from which device it is registered ?
Is there any way by which i can detect that from which device it is registered?
Please help me out?

Comment: Is there any server involved in your application?

Comment: yes,i have my own server where the information get stored,so when the user register his device i want to store the device information? do u have any idea??

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Use vendor ID as unique identifier for device.
2. Create GUID while
       doing registration of device.

Using these unique identifiers you may create table at server to identify the device and you will come to know from which device request is generated.

I hope this clears your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

When user register , store his device's `UUID`. And you can check for matching `UUID` from server everytime user logs in.

```
NSString *UUID = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
```

Comment: currently i have to check on my simulator,so i don't have UUID ,so please suggest me in which way i can check the user information?

Answer (score 0):

As `@Pooja M. Bohora` said you can create the unique number and then save it into the `UIPasteBoard` of device for further use. So that though your application get uninstalled from device you can retrieve that from `UIPasteBoard`

Check below link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

Here let say at the first time u have saved Unique no using key `com.companyname.appid` then next time use the same key for getting the unique no.

Also if you get `com.companyname.appid` as blank then only create new unique id and send it to server by saving it into `UIPasteBoard`